# Privacy policy generator

Tags: privacy-policy

Does anyone know of a all-in-one privacy policy generator that they have used and can recommend?

Comment: A quick google search shows lots of good free generators. Are you looking for anything in particular?

Comment: I'm tempted to close this as "too localised" as we've no idea what country you're in to suit your needs, but let's see how it pans out.

Comment: I'm in the UK. However after a search on Google, I wasn't pleased with the results as the none of the websites looked clean cut. And of those that I could find the link to generate a policy, I wasn't satisfied by their end result. So I thought perhaps that someone may know of a better site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've no idea what country you're in, so here's some that cover the major countries:

- http://www.lawlive.com.au/legal-website-privacy-policy/
- **http://www.lawlive.co.uk/legal-website-privacy-policy/**
- http://www.lawlive.com.hk/legal-website-privacy-policy/
- http://www.lawlive.co.nz/legal-website-privacy-policy/
- http://www.lawlive.co.za/legal-website-privacy-policy/

(It's about the same price nomatter which currency you buy it in, I have bolded the UK version as per your comment)

<sub>Full disclosure: I know the people that run this website. In fact I've worked with them in the past, and we use their services my workplace.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

This one's a little old, but I've used this free app from IBM to great success in generating privacy policies a P3P policies: http://www.alphaworks.ibm.com/tech/p3peditor

Answer (score 0):

Iubenda have a [policy generator](https://www.iubenda.com/en) with a lot of nice modular bits you can include, like which services are used on your site and hence what information is collected. They then provide you with an image link to the generated policy, a bit like Creative Commons licenses are often displayed.
There's also a pretty cheap "pro" option that allows for white-labeling and a few other benefits.